# How to stop script function from running when no data is present?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a formatting script set to run on a time based trigger, but have issues when there is no data present. The formatting process gets wacky and gives an undesired output in the automated email.

How can I add "if statement logic", and have the process not format if there is no data present?

```
function process_table(){
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet URL");
  var ws = sss.getSheetByName("Absenteeism Tab");
  // var dat = ws.getDataRange();
  var mws = sss.getSheetByName("Export");
  mws.getRange('A:I').clear();
  var lastRow = ws.getLastRow();
  ws.getRange('A1:H'+lastRow).copyTo(mws.getRange(1,1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
  ws.getRange('A1:H'+lastRow).copyTo(mws.getRange(1,1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT,false);
  var slr = mws.getLastRow();
  
  mws.getRange('I2:I'+slr).setFormula('=text(e2, "yyyy-mm-dd")');
  var copyIt = mws.getRange('I2:I'+slr).getValues();
  copyIt.toString();
  mws.getRange('E2:E'+slr).setValues(copyIt);
  
  mws.getRange('J2:J'+slr).setFormula('=text(f2, "HH:MM")');
  var copyIt = mws.getRange('J2:J'+slr).getValues();
  copyIt.toString();
  mws.getRange('F2:F'+slr).setValues(copyIt);

  mws.getRange('K2:K'+slr).setFormula('=text(G2, "HH:MM")');
  var copyIt = mws.getRange('K2:K'+slr).getValues();
  copyIt.toString();
  mws.getRange('G2:G'+slr).setValues(copyIt);

  mws.getRange('I2:L').clear();
  mws.getRange('E2:G').setNumberFormat('@');
  mws.getRange('A:H').setHorizontalAlignment('center');
```

I'm unsure of what to try for this specific issue. Because of odd time frames/formats of the original data output, I'm forced to modify it with script, but if the script encounters a lack of data it breaks down and the format gets crazy.

Comment: What is the "data" that you want to check for?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that is produced to help us understand and reproduce the issue

Comment: `if(data.length > 0) { process_table())`

Comment: @Luke McCrea, To keep it easy, I'd love to be able to reference one single cell on the "Absenteeism Tab", and if it finds text in that cell, then run the process as normal. If it finds nothing in the cell, then skip the formatting process all together.

Comment: @Cooper, thanks for the "if" logic, but I'm dense and not sure where exactly to place that within the script above.